# ssl "No trusted certificate was found”

Tags: ssl, truststore

I have trust store which contains Symantec. I am trying to connect to server which is signed by VeriSign. I am getting ssl "No trusted certificate was found” during the handshake. Can it be because I don't have VeriSign CA in trust store?

I am using Axis framework with SSLConnectionSocketFactory. With openssl I see the VeriSign certificate chain on the server

Comment: What do you use for connecting ? Did you debug this connection using OpenSSL ?

Comment: Axis framework with SSLConnectionSocketFactory. With openssl I see the VeriSign certificate chain on the server.

Comment: Great, so why not add these details to your question ? And I assume you need VeriSign in your truststore

Comment: I am assuming Symantec is root CA for VeriSign.I have Symantec in my trust store. I am trying to understand why I am getting "No trusted certificate was found" error.

Comment: You may be missing an intermediate certificate for building the certificate trust chain if the server was not properly configured to return all certificates in the chain except for the root.

Answer (score 0):

My problem solved after adding the VeriSign CA to trust store.